# UWP: Newline character while using multiple language support

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, uwp-xaml, multiple-languages

I am developing an app using Universal Windows Platform with multi-language support using Resources.resw file. I have a dialog with a textbox to show EULA as follows, in my page XAML.

```
<TextBox x:Uid="eula" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

How can I type my resources.resw parameter, so that a new line shows up on the content dialog.

I tried `\n`, `&#13;`, `<br/>`, etc. to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open any text editor, write your multiline text there

[image]

copy it and then paste into resources' value field.

[image]

The result

[image]

Comment: Now I feel really dumb!

Comment: Or just press Shift+Enter in the resource view to input a newline.